# What's the difference between hazelnuts and filberts?

Tags: difference

What's the difference between hazelnuts and filberts? Googling shows very similar pictures. I do understand that they belong to the same plant family

Comment: [Filbert and Hazelnut, Two Names for the Same Fruit](https://www.ijpr.org/show/as-it-was/2019-11-12/as-it-was-filbert-and-hazelnut-two-names-for-the-same-fruit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s truly no wrong answer. “Filbert” is the correct name for both the tree and nut. The name is of French origin, and filbert trees were likely first introduced into Oregon by early French settlers. Some thought “filbert” was derived from St. Philibert, as August 22 is dedicated to him, corresponding to the earliest ripening date of filberts in England.

“Hazelnut” is the name coined by the English and applied to the native species by early settlers. In 1981, the Oregon Filbert Commission decided to conform to the common standard and began emphasizing “hazelnut.”